# vim changes modification time of folder on saving file in it under windows 7

Tags: vim

I have been developing a perl application under Windows 7 that has a subroutine which lists all source files in a given directory. To spare time in the next run source files that had been found are written to a cache (plain txt file). Then this cache is intended to be updated only if there were changes under the source folders. I assumed that I can check modification time of folders to check if files were removed or added and update cache file only if needed.

It seemed to work well until I edited some of the source files with vim which updated the modification date of the containing folder as well. First I thought it is because vim adds a swap file to the directory where the edited source resides. So I set **directory** in *_vimrc* file to point to an other location.

```
set directory=~/.vim/swap       " directory to place swap files in
```

After setting it there were no added swap file in the source folder but the modification time of directory changed **after saving** the file.

I'm using gVim 8.0.586 for Windows but gVim nightly (8.0.1605), neovim (v0.2.2-1173-gc46d6f8da), cygwin vim (8.0 1-1376) gave me the same result even with a "clean" *_vimrc* that only sets *directory*.

Editing the same source file with Notepad++ or Atom changes only the modification time of the file and not the modification time of the directory containing it.

Does anybody have any clue what can cause this behavior of vim?

**EDIT**

I have also these two lines in may *_vimrc*:

```
set backup                      " make backup files        
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup     " where to put backup files
```

As Wumpus suggested i tried to switch off both *backup* and *writebackup* and it did work but i did not have any backupfile. :(

```
:set nobackup nowritebackup
```

writebackup is not set in *_vimrc*, so it is on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the creation and deletion of the backup file.

vim creates a backup before writing the new version of the file, so you can get the old version back in case of a crash.

You can turn off backups with `:set nobackup nowritebackup` or change the location with `:set backupdir=someplaceelse`

The `backupcopy` option may also have some effect. It can try to rename the new file into place. Try `yes` and `no` for `backupcopy` and see if there is a difference. But note there are other side effects... see `:help backupcopy`. And the behavior may depend on whether your `backupdir` is on the same filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! You are right if I set :set nobackup nowritebackup modification date of folder did not changed. But in normal case I have both of them switched on with the backupdir pointing to a different palce. See EDIT.

Comment: `:set backupcopy=yes` worked fine! :) Thank you for your help!